# Why the nested type must be explicitly declared?

Tags: c#, dictionary, initialization, c#-6.0

I think this is the first time I'm using the new C#6 dictionary-initialization feature, and I need a nested structure like the below one:

```
        var map = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>()
        {
            ["WNodeScramblingResetZone_Unlock"] = 
            {
                ["updater"] ="pinco",
                ["rdlev"] = 55
            },
            ["WNodeScramblingResetZone_NewPwd"] = 
            {
                ["updater"] ="pallo",
                ["wrlev"] = 75,
                ["is_online"] = true
            }
        };
```

This syntax seems fine: no compilation errors. However, when the program starts I see a couple of "KeyNotFoundException" errors in the output window, and the application does not work.

By the way, if I explicitly declare the nested type instantiation, everything runs fine.

```
        var map = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>()
        {
            ["WNodeScramblingResetZone_Unlock"] = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                ["updater"] ="pinco",
                ["rdlev"] = 55
            },
            ["WNodeScramblingResetZone_NewPwd"] = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                ["updater"] ="pallo",
                ["wrlev"] = 75,
                ["is_online"] = true
            }
        };
```

Is that a limitation, a bug, or rather there is a concrete reason to define it?

Comment: Post the error you are seeing here...

Comment: Initializers are syntactic sugar, you should see how IL looks like to figure whats happening here...

Comment: I think it's because of dictionary we need to create object of that class then only it will take value let say in dictionary key is string and value is any model class so in that case if we want to add data in that model so you need to first intialize it and then only you can add data .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write code like this:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>()
{
    ["WNodeScramblingResetZone_Unlock"] = 
    {
        ["updater"] ="pinco"
    }
};
```

It's compiled into the equivalent of this:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>()
map["WNodeScramblingResetZone_Unlock"]["updater"] = "pinco";
```

It does not create any instances that you didn't explicitly specify.

This is code that *could* work (which is why it's allowed) for some dictionary-like class, which returns empty collection for keys that don't exist, but will indeed cause `KeyNotFoundException` for `Dictionary`.

On the other hand, this code:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>()
{
    ["WNodeScramblingResetZone_Unlock"] = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        ["updater"] ="pinco"
    }
};
```

Is compiled as:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();
var tmp = new Dictionary<string, object>();
tmp["updater"] = "pinco";
map["WNodeScramblingResetZone_Unlock"] = tmp;
```

As you can see, this calls the `map["WNodeScramblingResetZone_Unlock"]` *setter* with a new instance (instead of the getter in the previous version), which is why it works.

Comment: "returns empty collection for keys that don't exist" ,,, or of course if it is created with some keys already existing

Comment: That makes sense. Pity! Let's say that _it would be nice_ having some syntactic tool to easily express structures like it was a JSON document or so. However, the compiler couldn't guess what is the actual type to be instanced. That is, I might want to insert a derivation of Dictionary<string, object>. I didn't realize that yesterday!

Answer (score 1):

I used http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/ to translate this C# code into VB.NET:

```
Public Class Program
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim expr_06 As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Object)) = New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
        expr_06("x")("updater") = "pinco"
        expr_06("x")("rdlev") = 55
        expr_06("y")("updater") = "pallo"
        expr_06("y")("wrlev") = 75
        expr_06("y")("is_online") = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

It cleary shows that new dictionaries are not created only accessed by key. The new `[key] = value` syntax compiles to `dictionary[key] = value` not like old one `{key, value}` which compiled to `dictionary.Add(key, value)`.

I think this is a feature, compiler doesn't know what type of `IDictionary` you need so you must provide *concrete* type. There is also posibility that you use some dynamic collection that automatically creates subdictionnaries on first access in that case this code would work. As you may see compiler leaves you great freedom to do what you want at the expense of program verbosity.

EDIT: I write a bit lengthy [blog post about initializers](https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/object-and-collection-initializers-in-csharp) that provides a more deep explanation

Comment: What `IDictionary`? I don't see that interface used anywhere in the code.

Comment: @svick I mean in the *inner* initializer you try to set values in some kind of dictionnary - why because you use *dictionnary* initializer. I used `IDictionnary` as a placeholder for types that can be used with dictionnary intiializers - OK maybe it is misleading but I cannot express it more cleary right now